# Openpyxl or the actual excel program adding "@" in my formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I'm currently trying to use this to find the standard deviation of a range while also ignoring 0 values:

```
WS[stdCoord].value = '=STDEV(IF(' + range + '<>0,' + range + '))'
```

When I use a print statement to print out that specific `cell.value` the line before saving the workbook, it returns

```
=STDEV(IF(D2:D5<>0,D2:D5))
```

which is exactly what I want. However, when I open up the excel file, the cell gives me a `#VALUE!` error with its contents being

```
=STDEV(IF(@D2:D5<>0,D2:D5))
```

I have no clue where this "@" symbol is coming from and no one else seems to be getting this weird behavior.

I've tried hard coding the exact string that I want, but the "@" symbol still appears. Even tried putting in random spaces in the string. Any ideas?

Comment: You got Excel O365 most likely? In that case, don't use `.Value` but `.Formula2` and see if that fixes it? If not, we can re-open again.

Comment: Is this specific to VBA? I tried using `WS[stdCoord].formula2`, but the cell object doesn't have a `formula2` attribute. I also don't know where the class `Cells` is coming from. 

I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this being implemented on openpyxl. Do you happen to have any links that I could have missed?

Comment: Then use `.FormulaArray`

Comment: I'm confused. What class is the `.FormulaArray` attribute from? cell objects don't have a `FormulaArray` attribute.